# Error when consuming SOAP Server in PHP with SOAP UI, "Webservice handler class not present"

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've written a PHP SOAP Server, using [php-wsdl-creator](https://code.google.com/p/php-wsdl-creator/wiki/Usage). And I'm having a problem consuming data from this  Server. I have a `doPing()` function that receives a string and returns a `"Hello".$thatString`. I get this error, when I do that from the SOAP Client:

> ( ! ) **Fatal error**: Uncaught exception
>   'Exception' with message 'Webservice handler class not present' in
>   C:\wamp\www\GDR\class.phpwsdl.php on line *1781*
>   ( ! ) Exception: Webservice handler class not present
>   in C:\wamp\www\GDR\class.phpwsdl.php on line *1781*
>   Call
>   Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0000257928{main}(  )..\hello_server.php**:**0 20.0000798296require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\GDR\class.phpwsdl.php' )..\hello_server.php**:**3 30.00001172088PhpWsdl::PostInit( 
>   )..\class.phpwsdl.php**:**46 40.00001172336PhpWsdl::RunQuickMode(
>   )..\class.phpwsdl.php**:**2441 50.00001177448PhpWsdl->RunServer( 
>   )..\class.phpwsdl.php**:**554

If you need more information about the Server or Client file, just ask - thanks.

Comment: Sorry, we are not mind-readers, so we cannot possibly comment on what may be wrong with your code unless you include the relevant parts in your question. Edit your question with the appropriate details (do not use an answer to add the details).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

https://code.google.com/p/php-wsdl-creator/issues/detail?id=1

In line 434 of file class.phpwsdl.php, if you set soap_version to just one of the versions (SOAP_1_1 or SOAP_1_2, not SOAP_1_1 | SOAP_1_2) the error is gone.

And also I had to set methods as Global Methods, as I didn't have a webservice handler class.

Here in usage it explains you how to do this

https://code.google.com/p/php-wsdl-creator/wiki/Usage